# CSS DIV alignment issues using VUE Components

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a vue application that has 2 components.  Each component is in a div of its own.  I'm using CSS that I found because I'm not strong with CSS.  Everything works great and is responsive but I notice that the top div and the bottom div do not align properly.  Both components do not stay the same width as the page resizes.  I'm using vuetify [grid system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids). How can I fix that?

```
<div id="app">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"><sp_card></sp_card></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"><sp-card2></sp-card2></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component('sp_card',{
  data: function(){
    return {
      num: 3
    }
  },
  template: `
<div>
  <div class="card" v-for="n in num">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>Card Title</b></h4> 
      <p>By | date</p> 
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`
})

Vue.component('sp-card2',{
  data: function(){
    return {

    }
  },
  template: `<div>
<div class="card2">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>Horizontal Card Title</b></h4> 
      <p>By | date</p> 
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`
})
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {

  }
})
```

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.card2 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 49%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/1f995e1d28f068fc0071358967196e66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using width in percents like this you have to compute the right value yourself. The important parts of css are these:

```css
.card {
  width: 15.66%;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.card2 {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0.5%;
}
```

This way the bottom card will take 50% including its margin and the top ones will take same width with same margin of 0.5%. Btw when margin is set in percent it is computed from width of the parent width in both directions.

`15.66%` is computed from: `(50% - 0.5% * 6) / 3` where `6` is number of left and right margins and `3` is number of cards in the top row.

Comment: Hi Jan, I honestly did the best I can to understand your answer but I just couldn't wrap my brain around it.  It worked though!  Thanks!